# Magento2.4 Order shipping address is not in well format

Tags: sales-order, shipping-address, magento2.4.2

Shipping address showing some code and some data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Admin Panel > Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > **Address Templates**

and please check and make sure there's no syntax or format break error. If it still appears please share something about how, where and some modifications if made to understand where could be the issue.